# Conversion for multiple style attributes in different plugins are not working?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have developed a few plugins for ckeditor which work by adding span tag with style attribute.

- [Letter Spacing](https://github.com/gauravjain028/ckeditor5-build-classic/tree/1.0.0.beta.2/plugins/ucletterspacing)
- [Line Height](https://github.com/gauravjain028/ckeditor5-build-classic/tree/1.0.0.beta.2/plugins/uclineheight)
- [Text Transform](https://github.com/gauravjain028/ckeditor5-build-classic/tree/1.0.0.beta.2/plugins/uctransform/src)

They are working fine when I make changes in editor but, when I initialise the editor with `<p><span style="line-height:3;letter-spacing:18px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;">safasfasfas</span></p>` only `text-transform`, `font-family` and `font-size` is working but rest of 2 plugins/style attributes are not working.

Is there any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Edit: 
I have conversion like below

```js
editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' )
            .add( downcastAttributeToElement( {
                model: {
                    key: 'letterSpacing',
                    name: '$text'
                },
                view: ( modelAttributeValue, viewWriter ) => {
                    return viewWriter.createAttributeElement( 'span', { style: 'letter-spacing:' + modelAttributeValue + 'px' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' )
            .add( upcastElementToAttribute( {
                view: {
                    name: 'span'
                },
                model: {
                    key: 'letterSpacing',
                    value: viewElement => {
                        const letterSpacing = viewElement.getStyle( 'letter-spacing' );

                        if (letterSpacing === undefined) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return letterSpacing.substr( 0, letterSpacing.length - 2 );
                    }
                }
            } ) );
```

Comment: BTW, for the future reference, it'd be good if you posted here the original source which caused you issues. It will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding below code in conversion.

```js
styles: {
   'letter-spacing': /[\S]+/
}
```

Now conversion becomes like

```js
editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' )
            .add( downcastAttributeToElement( {
                model: {
                    key: 'letterSpacing',
                    name: '$text'
                },
                view: ( modelAttributeValue, viewWriter ) => {
                    return viewWriter.createAttributeElement( 'span', { style: 'letter-spacing:' + modelAttributeValue + 'px' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' )
            .add( upcastElementToAttribute( {
                view: {
                    name: 'span',
                    styles: {
                        'letter-spacing': /[\S]+/
                    }
                },
                model: {
                    key: 'letterSpacing',
                    value: viewElement => {
                        const letterSpacing = viewElement.getStyle( 'letter-spacing' );

                        if (letterSpacing === undefined) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return letterSpacing.substr( 0, letterSpacing.length - 2 );
                    }
                }
            } ) );
```

Comment: Great to see that you found the solution! Without `styles: {  'letter-spacing': /[\S]+/ }` the upcast converters didn't know what it has to upcast so it upcasted the entire `<span>`, blocking other converters. Once you added the style there, the upcast converter upcasts the style and leaves the element itself "non-consumed" which unblocks other converters.